# How to get SMTP server name through PowerShell when $PSEmailServer is empty?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Windows 7, PowerShell 4.0. Computer is in the Windows domain.

I need to get SMTP server name (for using of the `send-mailmessage` cmdlet). The `$PSEmailServer` is empty.

I read [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124916.aspx) TechNet page about the `Get-AcceptedDomain` cmdlet. But I see this (on the TechNet page):

> This cmdlet is available in on-premises Exchange Server 2016 and in
>   the cloud-based service.

How can I get SMTP server name or its IP-address?

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard of an SMTP service locator, how do you expect this mechanism to work? If you have Exchange deployed in your organization you might be able to find candidate servers through a [autodiscovery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900169(v=exchg.150).aspx), but that seems a bit overkill

Comment: Ask your local mail admin. Seriously. One might have some success with querying DNS for obvious names like `smtp` and `mail`  but those are just guesses. Maybe the organization uses cloud mail, in which case you need more than just SMTP server's name.

Comment: Don't overcomplicate things. You can find it in your MS Outlook client. `File` > `Account Settings` > `Account Settings` > Double click your email address > Top entry `Server: xxxx`

Comment: Guys, I know the name of our SMTP server, but it is interesting for me how to get this name through the PowerShell. :)

Answer (score 3):

If properly defined, the SMTP server address, either host name or IP, can be set through the SCP record in AD or Autodiscover DNS record of Exchange Server. There is a [Powershell solution for querying SCP](https://vanhybrid.com/2012/11/21/retrieving-exchange-autodiscover-scp-information-from-ad-via-powershell/) but Autodiscover solution is shorter, so I'll go on with it.

This works on Exchange Server 2010 and later. It should work with Exchange Server 2007 also but personally I have never used it.

You can get the host name;
`$MailServer = [Net.DNS]::GetHostByAddress([Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry("Autodiscover").AddressList[0]).Hostname`

or IP address (as string);
`$MailServer = [Net.DNS]::GetHostByAddress([Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry("Autodiscover").AddressList[0]).AddressList[0].IPAddressToString`

Since the `GetHostByAddress(string)` returns an instance of class `System.Net.IPHostEntry`, you can have some properties to make use of. For details, please read [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.iphostentry).

PS: I know, that's not the best practice to use the index of integers for values, but `AddressList` is an array of strings. So it does not define a method such as `FirstOrDefault()` or a property like `DefaultAddress`. So far, that is the most optimal and practical solution AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the computer is member of a domain with Exchange deployed, and you want to use Exchange as STMP relay for `send-mailmessage`, you could ask the exchange configuration in the AD Configuration Context:

```
import-module activedirectory
$ag = "Exchange Administrative Group (ABCDEFGHIJKLM)" #enter your EAD
$c = "Acme" # Enter your company name (get this form ADSIEdit if unknown)
$sb = ("CN=Servers,CN=" + $ag + ",CN=Administrative Groups,CN=" + $c + ",CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=staff,DC=hsrw")

$server = Get-ADObject -Properties cn, msExchSMTPReceiveConnectorFQDN, msExchSmtpReceiveBindings, msExchSMTPReceiveInboundSecurityFlag -SearchBase $sb -filter { objectClass -eq "msExchSmtpReceiveConnector"}
$server | ft cn, msExchSMTPReceiveConnectorFQDN, msExchSmtpReceiveBindings, msExchSMTPReceiveInboundSecurityFlag
```

This will spit out the hostnames and port bindings of every receive connector in your organisation. You then have to choose which one to use.

As I don't know how much Exchange knowledge you have, I will stop here. If something's unclear, just ask.

Comment: I get error message: *The specified `activedirectory` module wasn't loaded as in one of directories of modules the valid file of the module wasn't found.*

Comment: [You have to install the module.](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd378937(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Hm... But on that page I see: *The Active Directory-Modul is available in the following editions of Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7: ... Windows 7*.  
I have Windows 7. Also I don't see the "Active Directory-Modul for Windows PowerShell". :(

Comment: [You need to install RSAT.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=7887)

Please read the install instructions thoroughly.

Comment: During the installation I get the message that it is already installed.

Comment: Thank you, @Marc. I installed it now, but when I try to import that module I get such error: *WARNING: An error of the disk initialization by default: "It can't find the server by default with working web services of the Active Directory.".*

Comment: This looks more or less like some more complex issue in your active directory. Above code works in a properly set up ad environmet. If it does not work for you, I'm sorry, but I don't see what I could do for you at this point.

Comment: No problem, @Marc. Thank you for your response.